# Python Pandas: Merge three DataFrames with a common date column without loosing any row on the final result

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge 3 dataframes that have a common date column (used as index)

**The first dataframe contains some values of air pollutans and precipitation:**

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════╦═════════╦═════╗
║ DATE       ║ PRECIPITATION ║ PM 10   ║ PM 2.5  ║ NO2 ║ SO2     ║ CO  ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-01 ║ 0.0           ║ 129.2   ║ 49.3    ║ NaN ║ NaN     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-02 ║ -9999.0       ║ -9999.0 ║ -9999.0 ║ NaN ║ NaN     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-03 ║ -9999.0       ║ NaN     ║ -9999.0 ║ NaN ║ NaN     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-04 ║ -9999.0       ║ -9999.0 ║ -9999.0 ║ NaN ║ NaN     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-05 ║ NaN           ║ NaN     ║ NaN     ║ NaN ║ NaN     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-06 ║ -9999.0       ║ -9999.0 ║ -9999.0 ║ NaN ║ NaN     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-07 ║ 2.7           ║ 78.1    ║ 24.4    ║ NaN ║ NaN     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-08 ║ 5.3           ║ 99.9    ║ 31.1    ║ NaN ║ NaN     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-09 ║ 0.1           ║ 116.5   ║ 36.3    ║ NaN ║ -9999.0 ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-10 ║ 0.0           ║ 100.2   ║ 30.8    ║ NaN ║ 5.0     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-11 ║ 0.0           ║ 113.3   ║ 34.5    ║ NaN ║ 4.4     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-12 ║ 0.0           ║ 85.4    ║ 28.6    ║ NaN ║ 3.2     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-13 ║ 0.0           ║ 55.7    ║ 16.6    ║ NaN ║ 2.7     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-14 ║ 5.0           ║ 89.6    ║ 27.4    ║ NaN ║ 3.8     ║ NaN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 2009-01-15 ║ 1.0           ║ 109.9   ║ 32.2    ║ NaN ║ 4.6     ║ NaN ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════╩═════════╩═════╝
```

...and the date continues until 2009-12-31

**The second dataframe contains max, min and avg temperature values:**

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦══════╦══════════╗
║ DATE       ║ min     ║ max  ║ avg      ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-01 ║ 10.1    ║ 13.1 ║ 11.47    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-02 ║ 13.3    ║ 18.7 ║ 16.38    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-03 ║ -9999.0 ║ 13.1 ║ -2490.10 ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-04 ║ NaN     ║ NaN  ║ NaN      ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-05 ║ -9999.0 ║ 20.8 ║ -698.73  ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-06 ║ 11.4    ║ 17.9 ║ 14.64    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-07 ║ 11.2    ║ 18.9 ║ 14.60    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-08 ║ 10.2    ║ 19.1 ║ 14.65    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-09 ║ 9.4     ║ 18.4 ║ 14.05    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-10 ║ 9.2     ║ 20.7 ║ 13.85    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-11 ║ 9.7     ║ 17.8 ║ 14.32    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-12 ║ 12.4    ║ 17.8 ║ 14.83    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-13 ║ 12.4    ║ 17.1 ║ 14.51    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-14 ║ 7.0     ║ 19.7 ║ 13.77    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 2009-01-15 ║ 10.5    ║ 17.0 ║ 13.93    ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩══════╩══════════╝
```

**And the third one contains number of ERA Outcomes:**

```
╔════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ DATE       ║ NUMBER OF CASES ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-01 ║ 63.0            ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-02 ║ 38.0            ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-03 ║ 33.0            ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-04 ║ 161.0           ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-05 ║ 192.0           ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-06 ║ 164.0           ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-07 ║ 149.0           ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-08 ║ 159.0           ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-09 ║ 42.0            ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-10 ║ 44.0            ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-11 ║ 154.0           ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-12 ║ 143.0           ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-13 ║ 165.0           ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-14 ║ 166.0           ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-15 ║ 153.0           ║
╚════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

What I'm trying to do is to merge the three dataframes and generate one with all the data indexed by the same date.

My code used is as follows:

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import pandas as pd

connection_first_second_dataf = pg.connect("dbname=db_1 user=postgres")
connection_third_dataf = pg.connect("dbname=db_2 user=postgres")

first_dataframe = psql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM \"VIEW_1\"", connection_first_second_dataf)

second_dataframe = psql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM \"VIEW_2\"", connection_first_second_dataf)

thir_dataframe = psql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM \"VIEW_3\"", connection_third_dataf)


dataframe_result = pd.merge(first_dataframe,
                           second_dataframe, 
                           on='DATE')

dataframe_result = pd.merge(dataframe_result,
                           thir_dataframe, 
                           on='DATE')
```

And the final result is as follows:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════╦════════╦═════╦═════╦═════════╦══════╦══════╦═══════╦═════════════════╗
║ DATE       ║ PRECIPITATION ║ PM 10 ║ PM 2.5 ║ NO2 ║ SO2 ║ CO      ║ min  ║ max  ║ avg   ║ NUMBER OF CASES ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-01 ║ 4.0           ║ 79.2  ║ 31.2   ║ NaN ║ 6.7 ║ 0.5     ║ 10.4 ║ 17.2 ║ 14.34 ║ 63.0            ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-02 ║ 0.0           ║ 82.2  ║ 28.9   ║ NaN ║ 7.3 ║ 0.4     ║ 12.5 ║ 17.4 ║ 14.76 ║ 38.0            ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-03 ║ 0.2           ║ 77.1  ║ 23.0   ║ NaN ║ 4.1 ║ 0.4     ║ 11.9 ║ 16.4 ║ 14.05 ║ 33.0            ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-04 ║ 0.6           ║ 53.8  ║ 13.7   ║ NaN ║ 2.3 ║ -9999.0 ║ 11.4 ║ 15.9 ║ 13.35 ║ 161.0           ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-05 ║ 0.7           ║ 50.4  ║ 17.0   ║ NaN ║ 2.5 ║ -9999.0 ║ 12.5 ║ 18.6 ║ 14.89 ║ 192.0           ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-06 ║ 0.0           ║ 76.1  ║ 23.8   ║ NaN ║ 5.1 ║ -9999.0 ║ 11.8 ║ 17.4 ║ 14.43 ║ 164.0           ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-07 ║ 0.3           ║ 97.7  ║ 34.0   ║ NaN ║ 9.6 ║ -9999.0 ║ 13.2 ║ 20.6 ║ 15.82 ║ 149.0           ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-08 ║ 0.2           ║ 69.6  ║ 20.3   ║ NaN ║ 5.5 ║ -9999.0 ║ 11.6 ║ 20.4 ║ 15.49 ║ 159.0           ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-09 ║ 0.0           ║ 87.4  ║ 26.3   ║ NaN ║ 5.2 ║ -9999.0 ║ 12.9 ║ 19.4 ║ 15.69 ║ 42.0            ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-10 ║ 0.0           ║ 74.6  ║ 19.9   ║ NaN ║ 3.6 ║ 0.3     ║ 12.8 ║ 19.0 ║ 15.52 ║ 44.0            ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-11 ║ 0.6           ║ 57.6  ║ 17.1   ║ NaN ║ 3.6 ║ -9999.0 ║ 12.5 ║ 20.2 ║ 15.48 ║ 154.0           ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-12 ║ 0.0           ║ 63.7  ║ 19.5   ║ NaN ║ 4.7 ║ -9999.0 ║ 9.9  ║ 20.0 ║ 14.97 ║ 143.0           ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-13 ║ 0.0           ║ 95.4  ║ 27.6   ║ NaN ║ 6.4 ║ -9999.0 ║ 12.6 ║ 20.8 ║ 15.45 ║ 165.0           ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-14 ║ 0.0           ║ 101.7 ║ 29.1   ║ NaN ║ 5.0 ║ 0.5     ║ 11.7 ║ 19.6 ║ 14.94 ║ 166.0           ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2009-05-15 ║ 0.0           ║ 112.5 ║ 40.1   ║ NaN ║ 8.0 ║ 0.9     ║ 11.7 ║ 19.1 ║ 14.81 ║ 153.0           ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════╩════════╩═════╩═════╩═════════╩══════╩══════╩═══════╩═════════════════╝
```

As we can see, first and second dataframe starts at 2009-01-01 and the third one at 2009-05-01, when I tried to merge the three dataframes into one, the final dataframe starts at 2009-05-01.

My question is, how can I force to my final dataframe to start with the values at 2009-01-01? (no matter if 'Number of Cases' column has NaN values from 2009-01-01 until 2009-04-31, I know that I don't have any data for these dates).

I have read the documentation of pandas, however I do not find any solution for what I need, sorry for my english too,

thank you.

Comment: In your merge pass the parameter how = 'outer'. Default is inner

Comment: it works like a charm, thank you

Comment: Glad that it worked, you were almost there on your own so did't post it as an answer:)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
result = first_dataframe \
         .merge(second_dataframe, on='DATE', how='outer') \
         .merge(thir_dataframe, on='DATE', how='outer')
```

Shorter code and the keyword is 'outer'.